# php select from a join table

Tags: php, ms-access, adodb

Still new to PHP! I want to select a number of products from a category name, but I'm getting no results. Any suggestions?

I have a products table and categories table created in MS Access:

**`Category`** fields are `CategoryID`, `ProductID`, and `Category` with Head, Sculpture, and Vase records. 
    **`Products`** fields are `ProductID`, `ProductName`, `Price`, and `Details`.

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 
$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\\ectserver\\AHARDEN2\\Database\\products.mdb";
//creates the connection object and define the connection string

$conn->Open($connString);

$selectCommand="SELECT ProductName, Price, Details FROM Products WHERE ProductID = Head";

$rs = $conn->Execute($selectCommand);
//opens a recordset from the connection object

if (!$rs->EOF){

    $ProductName = $rs->Fields("ProductName");
    $Price = $rs->Fields("Price");
    $Details = $rs->Fields("Details");

}

print "You selected the following product last time:<p>";
print "<div id=\"category\"> "; 
print "Product Name: $ProductName<br>";
print "Price: $Price<br>";
print "Details: $Details<br>";
print "</div>";


$rs->Close;
```

Comment: You have to use SQL JOIN, this is more more of SQL and less of PHP problem

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you explain more on that. The book I have doesn't show I need that for this, but I'm no expert so can I get an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sql command

```
$selectCommand="SELECT ProductName, Price, Details FROM Products WHERE ProductID = Head";
```

must be changed so that it pulls data from both the tables. You will use `SQL JOIN`for this purpose. You join two tables based on a common ID. An example will be like this

```
$selectCommand="SELECT ProductName, Price, Details FROM Products JOIN Category on Products.ProductID = Category.ProductID";
```

the above query will join the two tables based on ProductID field. You can of course apply where clause in the end of the query as you would with any SQL Query.

If this does not solves your problem, let me know so I can clarify it.

Comment: Maybe I've explained the tables wrong because it is still blank after I insert your script. It looks a little different than the book so still confused.

Comment: run the query in phpmyadmin first and then put it in the code. You cannot assume your query will work correct the first time.

Comment: this is in access 2010. I'll try it there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I don't think your example was completely right, but it did help me run a query in Access and find the right statement.

Comment: This was the actual query script: "SELECT Products.ProductName, Products.Price, Products.Details, Categories.ProductID, Categories.Category FROM Products RIGHT JOIN Categories ON Products.ProductID = Categories.ProductID WHERE (((Categories.Category)= 'Head' ))"; Thanks for helping me find it.